# Почему const не определяет константу

Tags: php

```
/*
    выше присутствуют несколько запросов в БД,
    которые при возникновении ошибки записывают ее в $notice
*/ 

if (isset($notice))
{
    // константа PAGE_TITLE используется в заголовке страницы

       define('PAGE_TITLE', DOWNLOAD); // определяет
       const PAGE_TITLE = DOWNLOAD;    // не определяет

    // разумеется объявляю через define либо const, но не две сразу

    function сontent()
    {
        global $notice;

            echo '<div class="title">' . DOWNLOAD . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="notice">' . $notice . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Если использовать вместо `define` конструкцию `const` получаю ошибку:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST) in...`
В чем тут дело?

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, синтаксис, по которому можно определять константы со словом const поддерживается только начиная с PHP 5.3. Инициализация одной const с помощью другой константы доступна вообще только с PHP 5.6. Проверьте свою версию

Во-вторых, в официальной документации сказано

> В отличие от определения констант с помощью функции define(), константы, объявленные с помощью ключевого слова const должны быть объявлены в самой верхней области видимости, потому что они определяются при компилировании скрипта. Это означает, что их нельзя объявлять внутри функций, циклов, выражений if и try/ catch блоков.

Собственно, именно ваш случай - попытка определить константу через const в локальной области видимости.

Ссылка на эту запись в документации:
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.syntax.php

Comment: Благодарю. "Инициализация одной const с помощью другой константы" "в самой верхней области видимости" идет у меня с PHP `5.5.19`